# curl fail to save into a file even when specifying output

Tags: file, curl

Im trying to save curl result into a file so I can analize it later using other tools.

```
curl https://www.revolico.com/compra-venta/electrodomesticos/search.html?q=lavadora&order=date
```

the command works fine and I get the result on screen. The problem arises when I want to save it to a file. I have read related questions in stackoverflow and I think this one is a bit different.

When I use the command:

```
curl https://www.revolico.com/compra-venta/electrodomesticos/search.html?q=lavadora&order=date > testing.txt
```

Nothing is written into the file and the outputs once again goes to the screen.
I tried using the output choice

```
curl https://www.revolico.com/compra-venta/electrodomesticos/search.html?q=lavadora&order=date --ouput testing.txt
```

But curl says that doesnt recognize the command and prints the result to the screen. Same result using "-o".

I used curl in a localhost web server and everything worked ok. I think the difference resides in size because I also used on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and it worked just fine too. Did anyone run into the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Place the options before the URL.** Using `—output` is the best way, as it doesn’t clobber stdout. If this change still “doesn’t recognize the command”, maybe it is a really old or fake curl (like in PowerShell)? I usually run with `-vv` interactively, as it can sometimes show things like *not following redirects* (see/use `-L` to automatically follow) — https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl

So something like the following might be useful, to either fix the issue due to proper URL placement and ensuring to following redirects, or failing that, showing useful diagnostic information:

```
url=https://www.revolico.com/...
curl -vv -L --output testing.txt $url
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The hole problem was the order of the arguments. For some reason when it is too much data to download it doesn't recognize the ouput option, not being the case for small web pages. Placing it before the url is the fix